# kubectl create doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: kubernetes

I am running the command

```
kubectl create -f mypod.yaml --namespace=mynamespace
```

as I need to specify the environment variables through a configMap I created and specified in the mypod.yaml file. Kubernetes returns

> pod/mypod created

but `kubectl get pods` doesn't show it in my list of pods and I can't access it by name as if it does not exist. However, if I try to create it again, it says that the pod is already created.

What may cause this, and how would I diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `kubectl` commands operate in the `default` namespace.  But you created your pod in the `mynamespace` namespace.

Try one of the following:

```
kubectl get pods -n mynamespace
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```